# On Windows 7, how do I fix my cmd.exe icon and remove cruft from the jumplist

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, command-line, jumplist, icons

When installing drivers for my Gigabyte motherboard, I installed a "Games" link which ran from a batch file. This was pinned to the taskbar by default.

As a result, it changed the icon for cmd.exe to the icon for Games.

I uninstalled the Games and it got rid of the icon leaving it with a white rectangle thing (I can post screenshots on request). There is also a link on the jumplist to open Games, which just opens a cmd window.

I've tried rebuilding my icon cache as per [Changing Windows 7 pinned taskbar icons](https://superuser.com/questions/72756/changing-windows-7-pinned-taskbar-icons/120705#120705), but this only removed the white rectangle icon, leaving me with no real icon.

c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe still has the appropriate icon in explorer, just not on the taskbar.

Any ideas on how to fix this annoyance?

Comment: Did you try unpinning then re pin the cmd.exe?

Comment: I've tried. It's not pinned to the taskbar any more. Just whenever I open a command window, the icon is wrong.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/296289/why-cmd-exes-taskbar-icon-changed-after-msysgit-installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it be finding the "quick launch" folder on Windows 7: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned and deleting the "Games" entry. This fixed it.

Comment: Based on this answer I just tried pinning and then unpinning and it reverted to the normal icon.