# Why cmd.exe's taskbar icon changed after msysgit installed?

Tags: windows-7

If you have shortcut to cmd.exe in start menu/programs folder and this shortcut has altered icon - cmd.exe will have this icon regardless how it was launched - with shortcut or without.
Particularly after msysgit's install creates "Git Bash.lnk" with git's icon and thus altering taskbar icon of every 32-bit console window in the system.

I understand that this question isn't specific to msysgit, but it was the way I faced with it.

The details is in the blogpost linked below:
http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/troubleshooting-git-bash-icon-replaced-standard-cmd-exes-one/

The question is - why Windows behaves that way? Is there any reason to behave like that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this works, but if you make a shortcut to `cmd.exe` in `%appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`, its normal icon is what you will see in the taskbar. Another odd thing is that this doesn't cause it to be pinned to the taskbar. If you open `cmd.exe` and pin it, you'll wind up with a second shortcut in the same folder, named `cmd.exe(2)`.