# Fix for Windows 7 bug where taskbar icons point to the wrong programs not requiring reboot

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Currently, some of my taskbar icons point to incorrect programs.  For example, when I click on my Pidgin icon, Google Chrome launches.  Also, my Google Chrome icon is totally missing (even though there are instances of the app running).  I've found discussion of this bug at the link below; however, the proposed workaround is to reboot one's computer in safe mode, which is really disruptive as this bug happens to me somewhat regularly.  Does anyone know of a better solution?

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-7-64-bit-ultimate-taskbar-bug-wrong-icons/e856e688-b51c-402a-9559-b34add9111c2

Answer (score 3):

A slightly better fix:

1. Right-click the task bar and choose Properties
2. Toggle the "Use small icons" checkbox
3. Click Apply

This seems to re-draw the taskbar and in doing so will fix the above issue.

Answer (score 3):

I found restarting explorer fixed this issue for me. In command prompt:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

For me rebuilding the icon cache helped. I [killed](https://superuser.com/a/120705/40550) explorer.exe, [removed](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/bizarre-windows-taskbar-shows-improper-icons-in-small-icon-mode.181107/#post-1205352) `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db` and [started](https://superuser.com/a/510174/40550) explorer.exe again.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue today. You just need Windows to call the icons again. Just find the actual program and right click on it and pin it to the taskbar. Do this for any programs in the task bar that are not displaying the correct icon. It should correct itself.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for my Windows 7 Pro, given that my pinned items are shortcuts to the app, not the app itself:

1. Unpin the shortcut.
2. Properties of the shortcut I want to pin / change icon / reselect the same icon / OK
3. Pin the shortcut: the icon cache for the taskbar is refreshed

Answer (score 0):

right click the wrong icon and unpin it from the taskbar.  close the application.  Open the application.  if the correct icon appears, right click it, select "Pin This Program to Taskbar."