# Windows 7 has mismatched docked program icons

Tags: windows-7

When I minimize a fullscreen program, which I do with Windows key instead of alt-tab, sometimes the icons for my docked programs are screwed up and have the icon for a different program in the dock.

Took a screenshot showing the problem, the program with 2 instances open is actually Chrome and not Spotify:

[image]

Sometimes minimizing a full screen program again will fix it, sometimes that just recreates the problem in a different fashion. It seems pretty random when it happens and can also happen when fullscreen programs crash.

Comment: It could be an icon cache issue similar to this...http://superuser.com/questions/518018/fix-for-windows-7-bug-where-taskbar-icons-point-to-the-wrong-programs-not-requir